How can I hide timestamp in Threaded Comments in Excel with EPPlus?
I need to hide the timestamp on a threaded comment in Excel using EPPlus v7.3.2. I know it is possible to set DateCreated explicitly but can not find an option to hide the field. Is it even possible?

How would you do it in the Excel UI manually (not in code)?  I didnt think it was possible.  If Excel cannot do it, Epplus will likely not be able to either.

@ErnieS I have not been able to do it in Excel so it is probably not possible. Just thought someone else could have a workaround since it does not add anything to the comment i my case.
